# Azure DevOps Pipeline PR Trigger from GitHub Randomly Stopped Triggering

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have multiple pipelines in Azure DevOps where the source code is in GitHub, all of a sudden, with no code changes, the PR trigger has stopped working, CI triggers still work.

I have tried the following:

1. recreating the pipeline in Azure DevOps
2. changing the service connection used in Azure DevOps
3. checking the triggers menu in Azure DevOps, everything is as expected, nothing is being overridden in the UI

The weird thing is, we have other repos with exactly the same config which work, I believe there is something cached in GitHub stopping this repo sending PR triggers to Azure DevOps.

Has anyone seen anything similar?

Pipeline snippet:

```yaml
name: $(Date:yyyyMMddHHmm)-$(Rev:r)


trigger:
  - master

pr:
  - master

pool: 
  vmImage: ubuntu-22.04

steps:
- bash: echo "hello"
```

Comment: When did it stop working?

Comment: @Matt Last week.